# OS Drive and Storage Drive

Tags: configuration, installation

Well on my computer, I can't install Ubuntu to my 750 and boot from it, but it does however, work from my 160, and I use this as a work computer, and I have 280+ GB of information that I plan to put and use on it.

So, it was suggested to me, after much frustration, to use the 160, as the OS drive, and the 750 as a storage drive. How do I get all of my files on that other harddrive and make it work as though it was all on one harddrive.

The programs would know to go to whatever folders for whatever they need, such as Banshee for music, etc. This is really... odd, and I didn't expect this to happen, so how do I do this?

Comment: Please specify what programs you use. It won't be possible to list a howto for every program there is. But generally: use file -> import folder -> then choose your folder

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes a lot of sense to leave the biggest drive for data, though it's unfortunate you can't successfully install on your 750G drive. Perhaps you should open a bug for this with the model numbers and everything?

As for how to setup your system to use the 160G HD for Ubuntu and the 750G for data, have you already installed? Assuming the install is already done and Ubuntu boots properly; you can simply mount the 750G drive in Ubuntu and use it normally to keep data files. It should be detected and visible in nautilus, as such:
[image]

If it doesn't appear there, you may need to do a bit more like see if it's detected in the Disk Utility (System->Administration->Disk Utility), and possibly format it if it's not already holding your data. [image]

Once your disk works properly and can be mounted from Nautilus, you can add it to mount points by editing /etc/fstab (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions for a good howto with details). From there, you could do things like mounting directories from your data drive to a directory under /home/*your user*/Music, for example, or creating links from these directories into one of the data directories in your home folder.